# Magento 2.3: Show content block in terms & agreement popup at checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, terms-and-conditions

I want to show one or more content blocks in the terms and conditions popup at the checkout page.

All of the business terms, revocation terms, data privacy terms are stored in content blocks and so this is one location which has to be up to date if there are changes. 
Copy & Paste all the different things is not safe if you want to be sure to have always the same law terms everywhere in your store views.

I want to put one or more

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="your_block_identifier"}}
```

into the content field in

> Stores > Terms and Conditions

and maybe some HTML text and all of this should appear in this popup Box.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please Can U folllow this Link, it is proper solution of create terms and conditions popup in checkout page 
[Checkout Poupup link](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension/terms-and-conditions.html)

Comment: No this is not what I want. This is the standard way of Magento. I have my terms and conditions in different static blocks. And I want to add this static blocks to the popup.